# Ajax (jQuery) PHP Script // move_uploaded_file-problem

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a **gallery-upload**-function with

- jQuery Ajax
- PHP

The whole gallery-function contains 3 parts:

**Form** as *view_create-char.php*

```
    <form id='gallery_upload' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <input type='file' name='file' id='file'>
     <input type='hidden' name='name' value='".$_GET['c']."' id='owner'>
     <input type='button' class='create_submit' value='Upload' 
     id='add_image_gallery'>
    </form>";
```

**Ajax Script** as *main.js*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add_image_gallery").click(function(){

        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];
        var name = $('#owner').attr("value");
        fd.append('file',files);
        fd.append('name',name);


        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/gallery_upload.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
                if(response != 0){
                    alert('file  uploaded');


                }else{
                    alert('file not uploaded');
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP-Script** as *gallery_upload.php*

```
<?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';

        $owner = $_POST['name'];
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).'.'.$fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO 
        characters_gallery (owner, image) VALUES ('$owner', 
        '$fileNameNew');";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

The goal is to upload the image with Ajax and insert two values inside the characters_gallery-table. First, the owner of the table, then the name of the actual image, generated by the PHP Script. **This works.**

But the actual file is not getting moved to the designated folder /uploads by **move_uploaded_file()**. It remains empty although the table in my database is filled with the two values **$owner** and **$fileNamenew**. What confuses me is that before I used this Ajax-Script this PHP-Script to move files to the uploads-folder worked fine. It doesn't work with the script though.

I'm grateful for any help

**Edit --- Reaction to warning concerning SQL Injections:**

I'm not sure if I'm using this edit like I'm supposed to do but it is an additional information. If I'm wrong, please delete my edit.

I tried to add prepared statements and wondered if I eliminated any greater risk of SQL Injection:

```
<?php
include_once 'characterfunctions.inc.php'; 
include 'dbh.inc.php';

        $owner = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
        $file = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES['file']);
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).'.'.$fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = '../uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO characters_gallery (owner, image) VALUES (?, ?);";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            echo "SQL Error";
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $owner, $fileNameNew);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Can you check the permissions of the uploads folder, this sometimes causes a problem

Comment: Your code looks fine, have you given proper permissions to the uploads folder?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding ../ to $fileDestination :

```
$fileDestination = '../uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
```

It looks like you are moving the photos to **includes/uploads** but in your notes it says **uploads** is located in **/uploads**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, track the result of `move_uploaded_file` and if `false`, do not do the next steps.

Regarding why it may be fail, it cloud be:

- permission issue - so let's check the permissions of the `uploads` directory that should be writable from PHP.
- `$_FILES['file']` is not a valid file - so check with `is_uploaded_file($fileTmpName)` and also check the variable `$_FILES['file']['error']`